# iterate through array in javascript and return in new array

Tags: javascript, arrays, iteration

i'm totally new to coding: i want to iterate through the array *input*, select the positive numbers only, then put them in a new array *liste* and then print the new array in the console. what am i doing wrong here?!?

```
let input = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, -11, -12, -13, -14, -15];

var liste = [];

function cut(input){
    for (var i=0; i<cut.length; i++){
        if (i>0){
            liste.push(input[i]);
            return liste;
    } 
}

var result = cut(input);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Your code is not valid: it has unbalanced braces. Secondly, if you `return`, the loop will certainly abort and not make any other iteration.

Comment: Learn and use [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll attempt to combine the points made in several other answers here, and add some more explanation.

## Fixing the For Loop, One Line at a Time

Most of your code is fine; the only issues are in your `for` loop. Let's review that from top to bottom.

```
for (var i=0; i<cut.length; i++){
```

You have the right idea here. However, in this `for` loop, you want to make `i` loop from 0 to the length of the array you're looping over-- not the length of the function you wrote. So you should replace `cut.length` with `input.length`. This way, `i` will loop from 0 to 14.

```
    if (i>0){
```

`i` is a number you're using to keep track of how far into the array you are. As mentioned above, for your array, it will go from 0 to 14. You're trying to check if the number at the `i`th position is positive, not if `i` itself is. To access the number at the `i`th position, you can use `input[i]` instead of just `i`.

```
        liste.push(input[i]);
```

This line is fine; nice work! You're finding the number at the `i`th position of the `input` array and adding it to `liste`. Because of the `if` statement before, this only happens when that number is positive.

```
        return liste;
```

This line will return the list immediately, exiting your `cut` function. You want this to happen only after you're done looping through all the numbers, so you just need to move this line after the `for` loop.

And one last thing-- you forgot a curly brace to end your `if` statement. Be careful with this, as it can mess up your program.

I've gone ahead and made all these changes. You can check them out in the following snippet:

```js
let input = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, -11, -12, -13, -14, -15];

var liste = [];

function cut(input){
    for (var i=0; i<input.length; i++){
        if (input[i]>0){
            liste.push(input[i]);
        }
    }
    return liste;
}

var result = cut(input);
console.log(result);
```

Some things to explore:

- What happens if you move `var liste = [];` inside `cut`, like in Shmack's answer? Does the code still work? Why?
- What happens if you rename all `input`s inside `cut` to something else? Does the code still work? Why?

Understanding these questions isn't necessary, but learning the answers may help you to get better at coding for the future.

## A Better Method

But wait, there's more! What if there was a built-in feature that could do this more easily for us?

Introducing [filter](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_filter.asp)!

`filter` is a useful method that all arrays have that lets them filter their contents based on a function that you give them. Using `filter` lets you bypass writing a `for` loop at all (although it is still good to practice writing them; sometimes they are very useful).

The function you provide to `filter` is usually written as an ["arrow function"](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrow_function.asp), which basically just means turning this:

```
function(input){
    //Do stuff
    return output;
}
```

into this:

```
(input) => {
    //Do stuff
    return output;
}
```

It's very useful for writing quick little functions, so I'll use it in my example.

To filter the array using `filter` and arrow functions, all you have to do is this:

```
let input = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, -11, -12, -13, -14, -15];
var result = input.filter((number)=>{return number > 0});
console.log(result);
```

Comment: filter just returns elements if the condition is true. Is there any way to change the value while constructing a new array using a filter?

Comment: @kta Changing values in the array you're filtering inside the filter function is an easy source of bugs, but you can use [Array.prototype.map()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_map.asp) to change the array's values. If you want to remove *and* change elements (or add some), you'll need the slightly more complicated but also more powerful [Array.prototype.flatMap()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_array_flatmap.asp) method. A quick map example that adds 1 to every number in an array: `[1, 4, -2, 3, 0].map((num) => {return num+1})`. If you need more assistance, ask a new question.

Comment: Thanks @Feathercrown :). I ended up doing filtering first to get the desired result then calling the map function in my particular scenario.

Comment: @kta Good idea, glad you figured it out :)

Answer (score 2):

Since I can't accurately portray in a comment what I would want to explain, I am posting an answer:

I find it much easier to balance braces when I format my code like so

```
function cut(input)
{
    for (var i=0; i<cut.length; i++)
    {
        if (i>0)
        {
            liste.push(input[i]);
            return liste;
    } 
}
```

And now its pretty apparent where the unbalanced brace is.

There are other syntax errors that others have already been pointed out:

1. Its not `cut.length`, rather `input.length`.
2. Your `if` statement needs to be `if (input[i] > 0)`, not `if (i > 0)`
3. `return liste` shouldn't be inside of the loop, rather at the end of the function, because once a value is found it will stop the loop and immediately return only 1 value inside of the array.

Here should be a working example of what you intended to do. Other than those few syntax errors, good job with the logic!

```js
let input = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, -11, -12, -13, -14, -15];

function cut(input){
    let liste = [];
    for (var i=0; i<input.length; i++){
        if (input[i]>0){
            liste.push(input[i]);
        }
    }
    return liste;
}

var result = cut(input);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

There are 4 mistakes in your code

1. i<cut.length, you have to check the input length not the length of the function
2. i>0 , it should be input[i]>0 , since you are comparing the input indecis
3. Curly braces of if statement is not closed
4. Return is not outside the for loop

After fixing all these it should work

```
let input = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, -11, -12, -13, -14, -15];

var liste = [];
function cut(input){
  
    for (var i=0; i<input.length; i++){ //error 1
        if (input[i]>0){//2
            liste.push(input[i]);
        }//error 3
    } 
        return liste;//error 4
    }

var result = cut(input);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 for (var i=0; i<input.length; i++){
```

here you want to user input.length not cut.length, because you want i to go through all the indexes in the input array.

You also forgot a brace to close the for loop

In addition you are returning from inside the loop, which means the loop is exited, so as soon as the first element is found, you will exit the function, so you'll only get one element in your liste.

Answer (score -1):

Questions like these can be solved with googling a bit but for now, it seems like in your second expression, you have `i<cut.length` which doesn't make sense. You have to change it to `i < input.length` because you want to iterate through the input. You also can't have a return statement because you will exit out of the loop. You can also use a higher order function like the filter function to return any number that is higher than 0. `input.filter((num) => num > 0)` Hope this helped!!